# Variable definition missmatch with WorksheetFunction.Match function

Tags: vba, variables, excel, match

I'm using the below code to find the `Match` function in VBA to find a transaction id in a column:

```
 findrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cell, _
           ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(temp_import).Range("B:B"), 0)
```

The transaction id (cell) I'm looking for is on `63,000th` row. I'm wondering if I have defined the variable `findrow` incorrectly and this is preventing the match function from working? I have defined `findrow` as an integer.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it as `Long`. xl2007+ supports 1048576 rows.

See this. This will give you an error.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 63000
End Sub
```

Now try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long

    i = 63000
End Sub
```

And since you are using `Match`, either use error handling or define the variable as `Variant`

If you search stackoverflow, many posts have been covered on how to handle Match in VBA.